# Need a macro to pull data from tabs

Tags: excel, vba

My spreadsheet has one "Main" sheet that displays info that it gathers from other sheets and populate a table. I need to grab the info from 4 cells that are the same in each info sheet. The data it pulls is name, hours worked, etc. and it's from cells c1, d1, u11, and i20.

The number of sheets will vary as employees vary but I can put a cell in a1 of the main sheet to indicate the number of employees. Each tab is named after the employee, but I'm hoping they are somehow numbered in the background by Excel?

Answer (score 1):

The following code assumes that your main sheet is the first worksheet in the workbook. In the first column the names of the individual employees is displayed (given that your sheets are named after the employees).

```
Sub GetInfo()

        Dim intCounter As Integer

        For intCounter = 2 To Worksheets.Count
            Worksheets(1).Cells(intCounter, 1) = Worksheets(intCounter).Name
            Worksheets(1).Cells(intCounter, 2) = Worksheets(intCounter).Range("C1").Value
            Worksheets(1).Cells(intCounter, 3) = Worksheets(intCounter).Range("D1").Value
            Worksheets(1).Cells(intCounter, 4) = Worksheets(intCounter).Range("U11").Value
            Worksheets(1).Cells(intCounter, 5) = Worksheets(intCounter).Range("I20").Value
        Next
    End Sub
```